# interrupt handling in device driver & poll

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

I'm going thorough some code that does roughly the following:

- Kernel driver handles an interrupt.
- There is 1 interrupt line, so when an interrupt happens, the handles read a 32-bit register which tells what is the reason for this interrupt.
- For each bit that is set it calls ack_irq() to clear the interrupt, and write the interrupt cause to a buffer in the driver for further read().
- Next, it calls wake_up_interruptible(), to wake up a User-space process that is sleeping on select().
- The corresponding poll() function does poll_wait().
- Once select returns, the User-Space read() from the driver.

While I understand the basic operation of only 1 bit, what will happen in the following case:

- Interrupt happens, and 1 bit is set.
- Handler calls wake_up_interruptible(). poll() returns.
- User space wakes up, start to read().
- NOW, **another interrupt happens** -> kernel handles the interrupt and calls wake_up_interruptible(), but now no one is not waiting for this event.

Does this means that the second interrupt will be missed? If so, what is the way to overcome this?

Comment: Assuming it is a circular buffer, and the user process reads until there is no more to read (and assuming proper locking of the buffer), the user process will just read the next cause from the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, it is a circular buffer, but lets assume the user process finishes the read() of the first interrupt, and just before it goes to sleep again on select(), the new interrupt arrived. The new interrupt will call wake_up_interruptible(), but the user process is not yet waiting for this event.

Comment: "just before it goes to sleep again" the new 'cause' has been placed in the buffer, so select() will return this next value. The call wake_up_interruptible() just does nothing (there is nothing to wake up because nothing is sleeping). Rember it is the OS that does everything. It grabs the CPU from the user process upon the interupt, so the user process does nothing, and returns the CPU to the user process after every housekeeping has been done. That is why the user process will not go to sleep.

Comment: Still, the select() is doing poll() in the driver. I understand that the new 'cause' is placed in the new buffer, but why would the "select() will return with the next value"? the poll() function is doing poll_wait(). If i understand correctly, the poll_wait() will sleep until someone wakes it up with a call to wake_up_interruptible(). In the case above, the call to wake_up_interruptible() happens *before* the call to poll_wait().

Comment: OK, select will not return the next value (sorry there) and your poll routines check the buffer. Then it becomes very important that the poll function works in an interrupt disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

The task of the interrupt handler is to handle the interrupt as fast as possible.

To communicate with the rest of the system, the ISR uses a (circular) buffer in which it places your `cause`. It does this while in an interrupt disabled state.

Once the interrupt has been serviced, the system continues. If the user process now wants to check the circular buffer for new events, it needs exclusive accesss to the buffer. Thereto it must disable interrupts (with a higher priority than the ISR). It disables interrupts, gets the next element of the buffer, updates buffer pointers or indexes and re-enables interrupts.

Would a new interrupt have come in, then it will not have been handled until the user process has re-enabled interrupts (the IRQ line stays high, the chips registers have not been read). Needless to say that this buffer access must also be as fast as possible (as little instructions as possible). Upon re-enabling interrupts the new, pending interrupt will be serviced.

Following getting this next item form the buffer, it hands it to the functional user process. Would there have been no items in the buffer, it will sleep. When an item has arrived, it will be woken-up, disables interrupts, gets the item, re-enables interrupts and returns to the user process.

In this way, no interrupts can be missed.